# How does Azure AD identify the Principal from a SSO AuthnRequest?

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, saml

I'm having trouble understanding how the **Principal** information is sent in the authentication request to the IDP (e.g. Azure AD) during the SSO authentication process.

I checked the **AuthnRequest** example shown in this Azure AD article, but it doesn't contain any information about the user that needs to be authenticated:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol

If the user information are not included in the authentication request, can anyone explain to me how the IDP will identify the user in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The `AuthnRequest` is a browser redirect to the Azure IdP. The Azure IdP doesn't know who the user is either. So it displays an Azure login screen in the browser. The user then logs in to Azure (now Azure knows who the user is) and the Azure IdP redirects the browser to the `AssertionConsumerService` (ACS) URL of the SP with the SAML [AuthnResponse](https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_res.php) from the IdP identifying the user.

The next time the user's browser is redirected to the Azure IdP by an `AuthnRequest`, Azure looks at the cookies and knows the user has already authenticated and immediately redirects the browser back to the ACS with the SAML `AuthnResponse`.

The `AttributeStatement` in the AuthnResponse identifies the user if the IdP has agreed to release personally identifying information about the user to that SP.

Of course, if the user does not have an account in Azure they cannot login. Azure will know who they are from their login information, which is usually their userPrincipalName, which looks like `username@example.com`.

As the comment suggests, the username can be in the `AuthnRequest` but this is not often used. The SP should not ask for the username as the username "belongs" to the user (although ultimately it "belongs" to the IdP) and the IdP may not be willing to release that information to the SP. If the SP doesn't need to know who the user is, just that they have permission to access the service, then username is irrelevant. Permissions are often granted based on the `Attribute` set in the `AttributeStatement` and this can be done without the SP ever needing to know the username of the user.

If the SP supports personalisation, such as preferences for a user, not knowing the username isn't an issue. A SAML attribute such as [eduPersonTargetedID](https://www.switch.ch/aai/support/documents/attributes/edupersontargetedid/) can be released by the IdP that has the same value for that combination of IdP/SP (to stop cross-service tracking) and the SP can use that to store preferences for the user without ever needing to know the username.

A common way of using SAML is to replace a username/password login screen with the SAML flow:

- user goes to https://app.com
- app sees the user isn't authenticated (no cookie, session or whatever). This is when a non SAML app displays a login screen.
- app redirects user to their IdP. Easy in the case of a single IdP. app does not use Subject in AuthnRequest.
- user's IdP displays the login screen for the IdP.
- user authenticates at IdP
- IdP redirects browser to the app's ACS URL.
- app inspects SAMLResponse, looks at the Attribute set and decides whether the user (still possibly anonymous) can get access.
- if, e.g. user has an Attribute "eduPersonEntitlement" with a value "http://app.com/entitled" then app creates a session for the user and "logs them in" to app.
- when user's session at app expires, app sends them back to their IdP to see if they are still entitled to access the app.

Comment: ACS = *Assertion* Consumer Service, not Attribute. Additionally, the SP can absolutely gather a username (helps with determining where to redirect the user to, if you have a large implementation with lots of connections to IdPs), and send that username along with the `AuthnRequest` in the `<Subject>` Element. Reference [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32381733/how-is-the-principal-identified-in-the-authnrequest-for-saml-2-0-web-browser-sso). Other systems (like Azure) send the username along with the `AuthnRequest` as a query parameter.

Comment: ACS, yes apologies, typing too quickly! I've updated the answer with regard to Subject in AuthnRequest

Comment: @AndrewK. that's exactly how I imagine it should work. What's baffling me is that the specification says the Subject element is not mandatory, not even recommended.

Comment: @codebrane in my case, the application never displays the Azure login screen. The user simply types in the application's URL in the browser, hits enter and he's in, it kinda authenticates the user silently without any prompt for username or password. Not sure if I'm missing something here...

Comment: how do you authenticate without a username or password? I've edited the answer to show how SAML is usually used for "login"

Comment: You can certainly authenticate without a username or password... Think of X.509, or Kerberos. You may not have typed on anything, but maybe your IdP is smart that way (like Azure, using either of those or the authentication that you did for O365. Some IdPs (like PingFederate) ignore the 'Subject' to give the user more flexibility on what their username is. This is why 'Subject' is Optional in the spec.

Answer (score -1):

In azure ad portal, after registering the application through enterprise application blade,we assign users and groups for the application .

[image]

- we can perform single sign on configuration settings where we give
  redirect urls , upload saml certificate.
- SAML tokens contains information about the user known as claims. A
  claim is information that an identity provider states about a user
  inside the token they issue for that user. In SAML token, this data
  is prsented in \ SAML Attribute Statement.
- By default, the Microsoft identity platform issues a SAML token to
  your app that contains a NameIdentifier claim having  value of the
  username ( user principal name) in Azure AD, which can uniquely
  identify the user. The SAML token also can contain additional claims
  like user’s email address, first name, and last name which can be
  configured in a section Attributes and claims , which are included in
  token .We can edit this section according to the claims required for
  the application about user principal.

[image]

**References:**

1. [SAML 2.0 token claims reference | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-saml-tokens)
2. [azure active-directory-saml-claims-customization(github.com)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory/develop/active-directory-saml-claims-customization.md)
3. [sample reference:SAML_Token_Configuration](https://docs.jamf.com/technical-papers/jamf-pro/managing-jamf-connect/10.19.0/SAML_Token_Configuration_for_Enrollment_Customization.html)

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for.